# Adding a character before a specific character in a string

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview

Im developing a CRUD in vb.net using a MySQL database with a DataGridView and when inserting serial numbers some have a ' which conflits with MySQL. What I need is: the program to check if there is a ' in the string and add a \ behind if it doesn't have it

```
 If Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Count = 0 OrElse Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count = 0 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Dim res As DialogResult = MsgBox("EDIT product?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
        If res <> DialogResult.Yes Then Exit Sub

        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.SelectedRows
            frm2.Label10.Text = row.Cells(0).Value
```

Comment: [String.Replace()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.replace?view=net-6.0)

Comment: i have tried but it doenst work
` If row.Cells(0).Value .Contains("'") = True Then
         row.Cells(0).Value.Replace("'", "\'")
        End If
`

Comment: IF not needed, replace unconditionally.

Comment: If you use SQL parameters to pass values to the database, the problem will be gone.

Comment: I suspect that Andrew Morton is correct. There's no reason that any text value should be an issue unless you're actually saving the data incorrectly. You can find my take on how to do it correctly [here](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html).

Comment: i tried to implement it to the msgBox and it worked like this: TextBox7.Text.Replace("'", "\'") thank you for the assistance

Comment: @JoãoFernandes `Replace` is a function, so you have to assign the result of it to a variable, e.g. `Dim newString = oldString.Replace("x", "y")`. But you should still use SQL parameters in preference to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the pattern,

```
    Dim s As String = "a ' in the string and add a \ behind if it doesn't have it"

    If s.Contains("'") Then
        s = s.Replace("'", "'\")
    End If
```

Replaces all occurrences of ' .